# New to SwiftUI trying to understand layout changes without (I guess it doesn't have ) Layout constraints

Tags: swiftui

The problem is I don't understand how to fix my Content View to the screen and handle things like rotation or even how to make other screen sizes dynamic. Below is my entire View code. When I create a new app out of the box it looks fine in preview, the way I like it. However, screen sizes change and all I know to do is put magic numbers, because there is no superview or frame to size from. Also I can't seem to clip at screen edges. So my background view is way to big. How is this handled in SwiftUI?

```
 import SwiftUI
 import AuthenticationServices


 struct LoginScreen: View {

     var body: some View {
    
         ZStack{
             backgroundLayout
             loginLayout
         }
    
     }

     var loginLayout: some View {
         VStack {
             welcomeText
             signInWithAppleButton
         }
     }


     var backgroundLayout: some View {
         ZStack{
             Rectangle()
                 .foregroundColor(.init(.sRGB, red: 0, green: 0.750, blue: 0.750, opacity: 0.25))
             Circle()
                 .foregroundColor(.blue)
                 .offset(x: 200, y: -200)
                 .aspectRatio(1/3, contentMode: .fill)
                 .clipped()
             Circle()
                 .foregroundColor(.green)
                 .offset(x: -200, y: 200)
                 .aspectRatio(1/3, contentMode: .fill)
                 .clipped()
         }
     }

     var welcomeText: some View {
    
         HStack {
             VStack {
                 Text("Sign Up")
                     .font(.largeTitle)
                     .bold()
                 Text("Sign In")
                     .font(.title)
                     .bold()
                 Text("Get Started!")
                     .font(.title2)
                     .bold()
             }
             .offset(x: -100, y: -150)
         }
     }

     var signInWithAppleButton: some View {
    
         SignInWithAppleButton(
             .continue,
        
             onRequest: { request in
                 request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
              },
             onCompletion: { result in
                  switch result {
                     case .success (let authenticationResults):
                         print("Authorization successful! :\(authenticationResults)")
                     case .failure(let error):
                         print("Authorization failed: " + error.localizedDescription)
                  }
             }
         )
         .offset(x: 0, y: 150)
         .frame(width: 200, height: 50, alignment: .center)
    
         }

     }



     struct Login_Preview: PreviewProvider {

          static var previews: some View {
              LoginScreen()
    
          }
     }
```

Comment: If you're using `ZStack` + `offset` you're probably doing something wrong. Use `VStack` or `HStack` instead.

Comment: How would I produce layers with either of those? And how would I clip the circles?

Comment: You probably want to have a look at [GeometryReader](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryreader). This gives you control over the drawings that you make. With the next update of swiftUI, you might also consider using a `Canvas` as background (though that's still beta)

Comment: I’ve tried looking at geometry reader with no success. Can you please provide some context of how it would keep my view with reasonable offset?

Comment: In understand your frustration, I've definitely been stumped by SwiftUI, especially in the beginning. It would be beneficial to break your question into answerable parts. Here's a rewrite of the *backgroundLayout* that makes background be the size of the screen and centers a circle at the bottom left corner: https://gist.github.com/Baglan/7d16fa2dc124a436eac6eb62fda5ac8c

Comment: Generally, if you state your goal and break the whole question into as "atomic" parts as possible, I'm sure the community will be able to help you, what you are trying to achieve does not, at least at first blush, seem impossible with SwiftUI :)

Answer (score 0):

After trying several things this is all I could come up with. It's not perfect and certainly not ideal, but at least it work somewhat as expected.

```
import SwiftUI
import AuthenticationServices



struct LoginScreen: View {

var body: some View {
    loginLayout.background(backgroundLayout)
        .statusBar(hidden: true)
}

var loginLayout: some View {
    GeometryReader {geo in
        VStack {
            welcomeText.padding(.top, geo.size.height / 10)
            Spacer()
            signInWithAppleButton
                .padding(.bottom, geo.size.height / 10)
        }
    }
}


var backgroundLayout: some View {
    
    GeometryReader { geo in
        let circleSize = min(geo.size.width, geo.size.height)
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.init(.sRGB, red: 0, green: 0.750, blue: 0.750, opacity: 0.25))
            
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .offset(x: circleSize / 1.75,
                        y: -geo.size.height / 2.5)
                .frame(width: circleSize, height: circleSize, alignment: .center)
            
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(.green)
                .offset(x: -circleSize / 1.75,       y: geo.size.height / 2.5)
                .frame(width: circleSize, height: circleSize, alignment: .center)
        }
        .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height, alignment: .top)
    }
}

var welcomeText: some View {
    GeometryReader { geo in
    HStack {
        VStack {
            Text("Sign Up")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .bold()
            Text("Sign In")
                .font(.title)
                .bold()
            Text("Get Started!")
                .font(.title2)
                .bold()
        }
        .padding(.leading, geo.size.width / 8)
        Spacer()
    }
    }
}

var signInWithAppleButton: some View {
    
    SignInWithAppleButton(
        // Add this below for Continue with Apple button
        .continue,
        
        onRequest: { request in
            request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
        },
        onCompletion: { result in
            switch result {
                case .success (let authenticationResults):
                    print("Authorization successful! :\(authenticationResults)")
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Authorization failed: " + error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    )
    .frame(width: 200, height: 50, alignment: .center)
}
}



struct Login_Preview: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {
        LoginScreen()
    
    }
}
```